# mouse wheel button function on a whole class made clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I found this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".blurb_click").click(function() {
        window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the Html part of the code

```
<div class="et_pb_blurb et_pb_module et_pb_bg_layout_darket_pb_text_align_center carre-blurb-homeet_pb_blurb_0et_pb_blurb_position_top">  
<div class="et_pb_blurb_content"> <div class="et_pb_blurb_container"> <h4>
<a href="/coaching-sportif/coaching-sportif-personnel">Coaching sportifpersonnel</a></h4> </div> </div> <!-- .et_pb_blurb_content --> </div>
```

to make a whole class clickable. 
I found it here : https://divilover.com/clickable-blurb-module-in-divi-theme/

But when I click on the mouse wheel button (not on the icon or the link to the blurb made clickable) to open a new tab, it activates the all scroll option.

How could we fix this, please?

Thank you,
Nicolas.

Comment: I started my message with "Hello" but it does not display. I'm polite actually :)

Comment: Post Your whole Code div with burb_click class without seeing your code it's difficult to tell what's wrong

Comment: Hello,<div class="et_pb_blurb et_pb_module et_pb_bg_layout_dark et_pb_text_align_center carre-blurb-home et_pb_blurb_0 et_pb_blurb_position_top">
    
    
    <div class="et_pb_blurb_content">
     
     <div class="et_pb_blurb_container">
      <h4><a href="/coaching-sportif/coaching-sportif-personnel">Coaching sportif personnel</a></h4>
      
     </div>
    </div> <!-- .et_pb_blurb_content -->
   </div> is it ok ?

Comment: Actually i can't understand what are you trying to do you want to make a clickable Div so whenever it gets clicked you want to Redirect to another page is that it..???

Answer (score 0):

If You are trying to make the whole Class clickable . Then
there's just one mistake in your code that you  forgot to include the class in the div  Just Add that class 'blurb_click' in the div and code will work fine

```
<div class="blurb_click et_pb_blurb et_pb_module et_pb_bg_layout_darket_pb_text_align_center carre-blurb-homeet_pb_blurb_0et_pb_blurb_position_top">
<div class="et_pb_blurb_content"> <div class="et_pb_blurb_container"> <h4>
<a href="/coaching-sportif/coaching-sportif-personnel">Coaching sportifpersonnel</a></h4> </div> </div>
```

Comment: Hello, actually i had already set the custom class but i copied the original code here (my mistake). My problem is when you click on the mouse wheel to open the link in a new tab, it does not open a new tab when you click next to the icon or the text but in the div. The code makes the whole div clickable but when pressing the mouse wheel button, it triggers the all scroll function. You can try it here https://divilover.com/demos/clickable-blurb-demo/
Thank you !

Comment: @Nicolas  I just Checked it's Working fine  i think there is something wrong with your mouse

Comment: Hello, i made a video screenshot. It works when i click on the icon or the "clickable blurb" title but not somewhere else in the div. Here is the link : http://nimb.ws/6HvjId. Thank you.